Automate Google Play Store Submission via API
I need to release a lot of apps and the task that is taking up the most time is initially setting up the Google Play Store Listing:

Now I had a look at the Google Play Store API, but it seems that is very limited and can not programatically set any of these things.
Can I really only use the Google Play Store API to upload images and new APKs?
